# c# how to get XML tag values from a simple XML schema

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I have a XML that I get from other application that its structure is like this:

```
<uid>1DE23B0B-1601-4E48-B8F5-7D3152A815A1</uid>
<status>1</status>
```

Is there a way how can I get the values **without** using `XMLDocument`, actually I even don't know if `XMLDocument` can load a XML with these simple schema.

Any clue?

Comment: It's not valid xml I think

Comment: this xml has 2 root nodes so it's not valid. I think you should parse it without  xml APIs of .Net (use regex. for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your pseudo-xml via regex like this:

```
internal class Data
{
    public string UId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public Data(string text)
    {
        string strRegex = @"<uid>(.*?)</uid>.*?<status>(.*?)</status>";
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

        var match = myRegex.Match(text);
        UId = match.Groups[1].Value;
        Status = match.Groups[2].Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your xml is not well-formed (has multiple roots) - you can't load it into `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` - you will get parsing error.

However, you can read it for example, with `XMLTextReader` if you'll specify `ConformanceLevel.Fragment` in its settings:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"c:\temp\test.xml", settings);
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        var nodeName = reader.Name;
        reader.Read();
        var value = reader.Value;
    }
}
```